# get panel body style extjs6

Tags: javascript, extjs, styles

```
new Ext.Panel({
        layout: 'absolute',
        id: 'mainPanel',
        border: false,
        bodyStyle: "background-image:url(wall.jpg) !important"
});

console.log(Ext.getCmp('mainPanel').getStyle());
```

I'm trying to get body Style with `getStyle()` method but it turns an error on console

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getStyle'

however `getStyle` is one of panel method but why this error or can anyone correct my code? thanks

Comment: Which version of ExtJs are you using?

Comment: In Ext4 there is getStyle method not on the panel itself, but on the body. You can do something like :
`console.log(Ext.getCmp('mainPanel').body.getStyle('background-image'))`

Comment: `getStyle()` is not a panel method in 4.1, you can use the zoran answer for body style. If you want to get normal style you have to use `panel.getEl().getStyle('background-image')`

Comment: style and bodyStyle are two different properties on the panel

Comment: @rhf, I've tested it on all versions of ExtJS. Up vote for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `bodyStyle` panel object property. This way it will work on almost all versions of *ExtJS*.

```js
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            title: 'Hello',
            width: 200,
            html: '<p>World!</p>',
            layout: 'absolute',
            id: 'mainPanel',
            border: false,
            bodyStyle: "background-image:url(wall.jpg) !important",
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
        console.log(Ext.getCmp('mainPanel').bodyStyle);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css")/>
```

Comment: differences from my solutions gived 20 minutes ago?

Comment: @Mr.George, Is everything okay with you? I was already writing and testing the answer before you post.

Comment: 20 minutes to write your code? xD ok thats nice, no problems for me

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not familiar with the stackoverflow code snippet, I only have 20 days of experience.

Answer (score 2):

```
new Ext.Panel({
        layout: 'absolute',
        id: 'mainPanel',
        border: false,
        bodyStyle: "background-image:url(wall.jpg) !important"
});

console.log(Ext.getCmp('mainPanel').getBodyStyle());
```

the property bodyStyle should have a getter and a setter by default, i can't understand which ext you're using so you can simply get bodyStyle assigned like this if the get method doesn't work.

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp('mainPanel').bodyStyle);
```

If you instead would like to get the value assigned to the dom property you can do it like this:

```
console.log(Ext.fly('mainPanel-body').style.backgroundImage);
```

Ext.fly returns the HTML element of 'mainPanel-body', which is the body of the panel.